# Extract Department each Employee worked for 6 months or more in a year continoulsy

Tags: sql, oracle

Please below data

```
Emp.       Date.      Dept
1.         01/21.     Abc
1.         02/15.     Xyz
1.         10/19.     Cba
2.         01/21.     Abc
2.         02/15.     Xyz
2.         04.        Uvw
```

Using Oracl Sql i need to extract for each employee in a year if employee worked in department more than or equal to 6 months get that department else current department

Expected result for above data

```
Emp.          Dept
1.            Xyz.  (Emp workes more than 6 months) 
2.            Uvw.  (No department with 6 months tenure so current department)
```

Comment: If I guess Date defines the start date, where is the end date for the employee? And what is the date format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

I have created the table and data according to the example.

```
-- Preparing the data
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
    EMP     NUMBER,
    DATE1   DATE,
    DEPT    VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    1,
    TO_DATE('01/21', 'MM/DD'),
    'Abc'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    1,
    TO_DATE('02/15', 'MM/DD'),
    'Xyz'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    1,
    TO_DATE('10/19', 'MM/DD'),
    'Cba'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    2,
    TO_DATE('01/21', 'MM/DD'),
    'Abc'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    2,
    TO_DATE('02/15', 'MM/DD'),
    'Xyz'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    2,
    TO_DATE('04', 'MM'),
    'Uvw'
);
```

--

```
-- Final data in the table
SELECT
    *
FROM
    EMPLOYEES;
```

[image: Table data]

```
-- Your Query
SELECT
    EMP,
    DEPT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            EMP,
            DEPT,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY EMP
                ORDER BY
                    DURATION DESC NULLS LAST
            ) AS RN
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    EMP,
                    DATE1,
                    DEPT,
                    MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEAD(DATE1, 1) OVER(
                        PARTITION BY EMP
                        ORDER BY
                            DATE1
                    ), DATE1) AS DURATION
                FROM
                    EMPLOYEES
            )
        WHERE
            DURATION >= 6
            OR DURATION IS NULL
    )
WHERE
    RN = 1;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope, This will be useful to you.

Cheers!!